# Debug assertion failed fprintf in VS 2010

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, input

I'm new in programming and iam from Tver.
There is a problem in program. I don't know where. I am using input file and output file. So, i tried to debug program, but i failed
I'm using a Visual Studio 2010.
Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int num[100];
void outc(int s, int ss)
{int i,temp,numb[100],k,l,t;
temp=s; i=0;
while (temp>0)
{
    numb[i]=temp%ss;
if (numb[i]>=10) numb[i]='A'-10+temp%16;
temp/=ss;
i++;}
l=i/2; t=0;
i--;
while (i>=l)
{
    k=numb[t];
    numb[t]=numb[i];
    numb[i]=k;
    t++;
    i--;
}
FILE* fooo;
    errno_t errorCodes=fopen_s(&fooo,"output.txt","w");
    fprintf(fooo,"s%d= %d\n", ss, numb); 
return;
}
int main()
{char c,strbuf[100],num[100];
char *res;
int k,s,i,temp,ost,s2,s8,s10,s16;


FILE* foo;
    errno_t errorCode=fopen_s(&foo,"input.txt","r");
    fgets(strbuf,1000,foo);


    if(strbuf[strlen(strbuf)-1]=='b')
    {
        strncpy_s(strbuf, strbuf, strlen(strbuf)-1);
        c=atoi(strbuf);
    k=0;s=0;
    while(c!=0)
    s+=(c%10)*pow(2,k);
    c/=10;
    k++;
    } else
    if(strbuf[0]==0 && strbuf[1]!='x') 
    {i=0;;
        do{
        strbuf[i]=strbuf[i+1];
        i++;
        }while(i!=strlen(strbuf)-1);
        c=atoi(strbuf);
    k=0;s=0;
    while(c!=0)
    s+=(c%10)*pow(8,k);
    c/=10;
    k++;
    } else
    if(strbuf[0]=='0' && strbuf[1]=='x')
{i=0;k=strlen(strbuf);
        do{

        strbuf[i]=strbuf[i+2];
        i++;
        }while(i!=k);

    puts(strbuf);
    k=0;s=0;
    for (i=strlen(strbuf)-1;i>=0; i--)
    {

    if (strbuf[i]>='A' && strbuf[i]<='F') 

    c=10+strbuf[i]-'A'; else c=strbuf[i]-'0';
    printf("%d\n",c);
    s+=c*pow(16,k);

    k++;
    }
    } else s=atoi(strbuf);
    printf("%d\n",s);
outc(s,2);
outc(s,8);
FILE* fooo;
    errno_t errorCodep=fopen_s(&fooo,"output.txt","w");
    fprintf(fooo,"s10= %d\n", s);
outc(s,16);
//if (temp%16>=10)  num[len-1]='A'-10+temp%16;
//printf("s2= %d\ns8= %d\ns10= %d\ns16= %d\n", s2, s8, s, s16);

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `FILE* fooo;  errno_t errorCodes=fopen_s(&fooo,"output.txt","w");`  **??**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan See e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: You might want to check if the file actually was opened before using it.

Answer (score 1):

This has numerous issues:

1. You can't `#include <iostream>` or have `using namespace std` in a C program.
2. There are so many compiler specific things in here that it's going to be hard for most people to help you. You'll make your life a lot easier by writing in standard C. There's no way for me to compile this program to check what's wrong with it, for instance.
3. Your code is very hard to follow when you use variable names like `k`, and `s`, and `s2`, and the like, and do things like `FILE * foo` followed by `FILE * fooo`. Your code is also just formatted horribly.
4. With `strncpy_s(strbuf, strbuf, ...)` unless Microsoft is doing something really weird, here, you can't specify the same string as both the source and destination.
5. `strtol()` is better here than `atoi()`.
6. You're not closing any of the files you open, and you're not checking whether they did, in fact, open. Using the `&` operator here: `errorCode=fopen_s(&foo, ...` is highly suspicious, but again, you're using some non-standard function, so who knows.
7. Here: `fprintf(fooo,"s%d= %d\n", ss, numb)` you tell `fprintf()` to expect two `int`s, but the last argument is an array.